# AsyncContext of Servlet 3.0 is giving only ServletResponse

Tags: java, http-headers, servlet-3.0

I am using AsyncContext in my servlet for some asynchronous communication. As a response to asynchronous request I send some binary data (image content) which I would like to gzip for faster communication. But the response object provided by AsyncContext is just ServletResponse where I cannot set the http headers in order to send the GZIPOutputStream to browser. Is there a way to set headers for asynchronous communication.

```
AsyncContext asyncContext= request.startAsync(request, response);
ServletResponse aResponse = asyncContext.getResponse();
 aResponse.setContentType("image/png");
............................
```

Comment: Cast it to the http equivalent.

Comment: But GZIPInputStream is not supported by AsyncContext. I tried to compress every request that comes in using a servlet filter with url patterns as *, and when control comes to this line AsyncContext asyncContext= request.startAsync(request, response); it is throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not supported. exception.

Comment: `GZIPInputStream` is completely unrelated to the problem. It seems you haven't enabled async processing in your web.xml for your Servlet.

Comment: No, it is enabled using annotation like this @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/shoutServlet"}, asyncSupported=true), actually I want ot gzip request and response both.

Comment: I'd ask that you post some minimal code that will reproduce the issue. Also post the full exception stack trace.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot paste the code properly here :'  @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync(request, response);
        asyncContext.setTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
        contexts.add(asyncContext);
        System.out.println("inside doGet");
        
    }'

Comment: Ahh, don't do that. Please edit your question and post it there. Also, don't forget all relevant parts, servlet configuration, deployment. The stacktrace is also important.

Comment: see https://github.com/leonardoxh/spring-gzip-filter/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/leonardoxh/gzipfilter/GZIPResponseStream.java